# Scheduling a Google Batch job to trigger on GCP (long running Python script)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cron, batch-processing, scheduler

By "Google Batch" I'm referring to the new service Google launched about a month or so ago.

https://cloud.google.com/batch

I have a Python script which takes a few minutes to execute at the moment. However with the data it will soon be processing in the next few months this execution time will go from minutes to **hours**. This is why I am not using Cloud Function or Cloud Run to run this script, both of these have a max 60 minute execution time.

Google Batch came about recently and I wanted to explore this as a possible method to achieve what I'm looking for **without** just using Compute Engine.

However documentation is sparse across the internet and I can't find a method to "trigger" an already created Batch job by using Cloud Scheduler. I've already successfully manually created a batch job which runs my docker image. Now I need something to trigger this batch job 1x a day, **thats it**. It would be wonderful if Cloud Scheduler could serve this purpose.

I've seen 1 article describing using GCP Workflow to create a a new Batch job on a cron determined by Cloud Scheduler. Issue with this is its creating a new batch job every time, not simply **re-running** the already existing one. To be honest I can't even re-run an already executed batch job on the GCP website itself so I don't know if its even possible.

https://www.intertec.io/resource/python-script-on-gcp-batch

Lastly, I've even explored the official Google Batch Python library and could not find anywhere in there some built in function which allows me to "call" a previously created batch job and just re-run it.

https://github.com/googleapis/python-batch

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Batch but familiar with Google Cloud generally. From a quick read, it appears that Batch Jobs, when created, are run. There's no (obvious?) mechanism to rerun a completed Job. An authenticated (!) `POST`'ing to the endpoint documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/create-run-job) is what you'll want to specify as the HTTP target (!) for Cloud Scheduler.

Comment: Because Cloud Scheduler has a limited set of types that it supports, you can't provide it with Batch "types" directly, i.e. if you create the Batch Job using Google's Python SDK, you'll need to convert it into JSON to pass it to Google's Cloud Scheduler Python SDK because, an HTTP target expects e.g. a URI and a (JSON) message body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote this for you this morning as a guide.

It uses Google's [example](https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/create-run-job#api) in combination with Cloud Scheduler:

```py
# Used to correctly (!?) form Batch Job
import google.cloud.batch_v1.types

import google.cloud.scheduler_v1
import google.cloud.scheduler_v1.types

import os


project = os.getenv("PROJECT")
number = os.getenv("NUMBER")
location = os.getenv("LOCATION")
job = os.getenv("JOB")

# Batch Job
# Create Batch Job using batch_v1.types
# Alternatively, create this from scratch
batch_job = google.cloud.batch_v1.types.Job(
    priority=0,
    task_groups=[
        google.cloud.batch_v1.types.TaskGroup(
            task_spec=google.cloud.batch_v1.types.TaskSpec(
                runnables=[
                    google.cloud.batch_v1.types.Runnable(
                        container=google.cloud.batch_v1.types.Runnable.Container(
                            image_uri="gcr.io/google-containers/busybox",
                            entrypoint="/bin/sh",
                            commands=[
                                "-c",
                                "echo \"Hello world! This is task ${BATCH_TASK_INDEX}. This job has a total of ${BATCH_TASK_COUNT} tasks.\""
                            ],
                        ),
                    ),
                ],
                compute_resource=google.cloud.batch_v1.types.ComputeResource(
                    cpu_milli=2000,
                    memory_mib=16,
                )
            ),
            task_count=1,
            parallelism=1,
        ),
    ],
    allocation_policy=google.cloud.batch_v1.types.AllocationPolicy(
        location=google.cloud.batch_v1.types.AllocationPolicy.LocationPolicy(
           allowed_locations=[
            f"regions/{location}",
           ], 
        ),
        instances=[
            google.cloud.batch_v1.types.AllocationPolicy.InstancePolicyOrTemplate(
                policy=google.cloud.batch_v1.types.AllocationPolicy.InstancePolicy(
                    machine_type="e2-standard-2",
                ),
            ),
        ],
    ),
    labels={
        "stackoverflow":"73966292",
    },
    logs_policy=google.cloud.batch_v1.types.LogsPolicy(
        destination=google.cloud.batch_v1.types.LogsPolicy.Destination.CLOUD_LOGGING,
    ),
)

# Convert the Google Batch Job into JSON
# Google uses Proto Python
# https://proto-plus-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/messages.html?highlight=JSON#serialization
batch_json=google.cloud.batch_v1.types.Job.to_json(batch_job)
print(batch_json)

# Convert JSON to bytes as required for body by Cloud Scheduler
body=batch_json.encode("utf-8")

# Run hourly on the hour (HH:00)
schedule = "0 * * * *"

parent = f"projects/{project}/locations/{location}"
name = f"{parent}/jobs/{job}"
uri = f"https://batch.googleapis.com/v1/{parent}/jobs?job_id={job}"

service_account_email = f"{number}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"

scheduler_job = google.cloud.scheduler_v1.types.Job(
    name=name,
    description="description",
    http_target=google.cloud.scheduler_v1.types.HttpTarget(
        uri=uri,
        http_method=google.cloud.scheduler_v1.types.HttpMethod(
            google.cloud.scheduler_v1.types.HttpMethod.POST,
        ),
        oauth_token=google.cloud.scheduler_v1.types.OAuthToken(
            service_account_email=service_account_email,
        ),
        body=body,
    ),
    schedule=schedule,
)

scheduler_json=google.cloud.scheduler_v1.Job.to_json(scheduler_job)
print(scheduler_job)

request = google.cloud.scheduler_v1.CreateJobRequest(
    parent=parent,
    job=scheduler_job,
)

scheduler_client = google.cloud.scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient()
print(
    scheduler_client.create_job(
        request=request
    )
)
```

You can test using:

```bash
BILLING="..."
PROJECT="..."
LOCATION="..." # E.g. us-west1

JOB="tester"

ACCOUNT="tester"
EMAIL="${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"

# Create Project and enable Billing
gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}
gcloud beta billing projects link ${PROJECT} \
--billing-account=${BILLING}

# Enable Cloud Scheduler and Cloud Run
SERVICES=(
  "batch"
  "cloudscheduler"
  "compute"
)
for SERVICE in ${SERVICES[@]}
do
  gcloud services enable ${SERVICE}.googleapis.com \
  --project=${PROJECT}
done

# Create Service Account
gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# IAM
# https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-scheduler-roles
ROLES=(
  "roles/batch.jobsEditor"
  "roles/cloudscheduler.admin"
)
for ROLE in ${ROLES[@]}
do
  gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
  --member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
  --role=${ROLE}
done

# ActAs
NUMBER=$(\
  gcloud projects describe ${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(projectNumber)")
COMPUTE_ENGINE="${NUMBER}-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding ${COMPUTE_ENGINE} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role="roles/iam.serviceAccountUser" \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Then:

```bash
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate

# Or requirements.txt
python3 -m pip install google-cloud-batch
python3 -m pip install google-cloud-scheduler

export JOB
export LOCATION
export NUMBER
export PROJECT

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json

python3 main.py
```

Comment: This is incredible, thank you! Will do a test. Speaking of test, the bash script you included where would you execute that code? Locally or in the Google CLI?

Comment: You're welcome. Your question piqued my interest. I'd run the bash script on my local development machine but you could run it on an Linux VM with `gcloud` installed including Cloud Shell. Just be mindful that it creates a Service Account key so you should treat that with care.

Answer (score 1):

There is a misunderstanding. When you use Cloud Run jobs, you create a configuration and you execute a configuration.

BUT, with Batch job, you execute a configuration. That's all, no configuration to create in advance.

Have a look to the [APIs](https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/reference/rest): Create, Get, Delete. No more.

Therefore, you have to set in your Cloud Scheduler, the whole Batch configuration to create a new job.  Take care to NOT set the jobID in the query parameter.

Comment: So if I were to use Cloud Scheduler to create a batch job, I would send an HTTP Post to the appropriate batch API endpoint and within the body of the Cloud Scheduler job I would pass in an entire json as shown here: 

https://cloud.google.com/batch/docs/reference/rest/v1alpha/projects.locations.jobs/create

Does that sound right?